# Is it Encouraged to Use Closures to "Save" Values within React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, closures, react-hooks

Here is some code to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState(["a", "b", "c"]);
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  let listBefore;

  const addItem = () => {
    listBefore = list;
    setList([text, ...list]);

    //simulate api call "addNewItem(newItem, confirmAdd)"
    setTimeout(() => confirmAdd(false), 2000);
  };

  const confirmAdd = success => {
    if (!success) {
      setList(listBefore);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {list.toString()}
      <input onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={addItem}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The goal is to immediately update the UI before I know that the new list item was successfully added to the database. In the off chance that it failed, I revert back using my `listBefore` variable. I have been trying to figure out why this works and stumbled across closure. My guess is that, even though many rerenders may occur before the request succeeds (and `listBefore` is recreated as undefined), `listBefore` is "remembered" inside `confirmAdd()` because it had the value at the time of being called.

So I am wondering:

1. Am I correct in understanding how closure is being applied?
2. Is this encouraged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes your thought of closure is correct.
2. It works but it is not encouraged, because this is hard to understand, and tracking when reading or debugging code. You should use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to sotre beforeList in this case.

Comment: useRef would be the way to go huh. Would it make more sense to just define listBefore outside of the function component? That way it is not subject to being recreated between renders, and does not need to rely on the mercy of closures?

Comment: @Numnumberry Yes you can do that too. But personally, I prefer `useRef` way because `listBefore` is a variable is used and changed in Component lifecycle. I usually create a variable out of the component when it is constant, never be changed in Component lifecycle.